# How can I terminate port forwarding on connection with broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am on a connection that keeps dropping out which is annoying, but I can't do much about it atm. I am connecting to SSH using -R 9000:localhost:9000 (to debug with xdebug).

The problem is when I get disconnected and reconnect, the server still sees the previous connection on port 9000, and when I try to load a webpage, the server is trying to send XDEBUG data to the dead SSH connection.

If I run `netstat -nlp | grep 9000` I can see that there is an old connection open and I can kill it. If i reconnect after that, then the port forwarding goes to the new connection and everything starts working again.

Is there any way to either have the server kill that process when there is a broken pipe? (I'm thinking it might not know the connection is broken)

OR

Is there a way that when I connect back to SSH with port forwarding for the same port it will recognize that there is already another connection open (the dead connection) and kill that process so that the new connection will accept the port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

You told us nothing about your local OS, the remote OS, SSH client and server you're using. I'm assuming OpenSSH in Linux.

> Is there any way to either have the server kill that process when there is a broken pipe? (I'm thinking it might not know the connection is broken)

Low enough (yet not zero) values of [`ClientAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) and [`ClientAliveCountMax`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server should do this.

> `ClientAliveInterval`
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, `sshd(8)` will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is `0`, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.

> `ClientAliveCountMax`
> Sets the number of client alive messages which may be sent without `sshd(8)` receiving any messages back from the client. If this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, `sshd` will disconnect the client, terminating the session. […]

These settings are exactly for detecting broken connections. You can read more in [this another answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618). The following example values

```
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 4
```

will make the SSH server detect a broken connection and terminate it (release the port) after about a minute. You may want even lower `ClientAliveInterval` for faster termination. Note if your connection is unstable and sometimes stalls, but then resumes without really disconnecting you, a value that is too low may let the server disconnect you anyway in such circumstances.

Setting the same values for [`ServerAliveInternal`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ServerAliveInterval) and [`ServerAliveCountMax`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ServerAliveCountMax) in your local `ssh_config` (or rather your personal `~/.ssh/config`) is a good idea. This way when your client gives up on a connection, you know the server does the same pretty much simultaneously.

There's one more thing you can do. I really don't know Xdebug, I have no experience with it whatsoever, but I found this:

> [`string xdebug.remote_host = localhost`](https://2.xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_host)
>
> Selects the host where the debug client is running, you can either use a host name, IP address, or `unix:///path/to/sock` for a Unix domain socket. […]
>
> Support for Unix domain sockets was introduced in Xdebug 2.6.

I guess if instead of `ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 …` you use like

```
ssh -R /home/dab/xdebug-socket:localhost:9000 …
```

(yes, `ssh` can forward a socket this way) and tell Xdebug to use

```
xdebug.remote_host = unix:///home/dab/xdebug-socket
```

then it will work. And now you can take advantage of [`StreamLocalBindUnlink`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StreamLocalBindUnlink) in `sshd_config` on the server:

> `StreamLocalBindUnlink`
> Specifies whether to remove an existing Unix-domain socket file for local or remote port forwarding before creating a new one. If the socket file already exists and `StreamLocalBindUnlink` is not enabled, `sshd` will be unable to forward the port to the Unix-domain socket file. This option is only used for port forwarding to a Unix-domain socket file.
>
> The argument must be `yes` or `no`. The default is `no`.

Use the socket, tell the SSH server `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes`, then you will be able to recreate the tunnel even if the old SSH session is not terminated yet.

Note that unlinking a socket does not disturb programs already using it (like [unlinking a regular file does not disturb programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146930/108618)). Xdebug may still use the unlinked socket. Again, I don't know Xdebug. Do your own tests.

It may be you will manage to configure the first method (alive messages) and it will turn out to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* that this will work (worked in my experiments, albeit, I could only interrupt the connection manually, so not sure if I replicated exactly your broken pipe scenario):

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=true -R 9000:localhost:9000 -Nf remote-server
```

The main trick is that you are creating a "standalone" ssh connection only for the purpose of port forwarding and putting it into the background (`-Nf` options).  This way, when the connection terminates (broken pipe, e.g.), it should free the port.

The `ExitOnForwardFailure` option is only there so that the next time you try to make a connection, you will see on STDOUT the fact that the port is still open on the server.  If you still need to do something more complicated to manually kill the connection on the server, you could use the exit code from a failed `ssh` with the `ExitOnForwardFailure` option to do something more complicated.